# C preprocessor: #define a macro that can be called without parentheses

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if it is possible to write a macro which behaves like this:

```
void Func(int x)
{
    printf("%d",x);
}

#define func Func x //or something

int main()
{
    func 10; //<---- remove parenthesis
}
```

In this case, `func` will point to the real function `Func`, and 10 will be its argument without the parenthesis.

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the `new` operator in C++ but in C.

Example:

```
class Base* b = new(Base);
```

In this case, `class` is a macro for `struct`, `new` is a function which takes a function pointer, and `Base` is a function which allocates memory for `struct Base`.

I would like to rewrite the code to something like this:

```
class Base* b = new Base;
```

Which will be possible if I can come up with a macro :)

Comment: Shouldn't a macro parameter be in parentheses?

Comment: Well, those "function macros" have normal function syntax, like `#define func(x) Func(x)`. The call would be like a normal function, e.g. `func(10)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ehsan it is not a C++ question, its pure C and have everything to do with preprocessors mate

Comment: Attempting to change syntax of the language using macros is typically frowned upon, as its seen as incomprehensible and generally unmaintainable for anyone but the original author. And that "anyone" can include *yourself* in a few months. If you want to write C++ code, then program in C++.

Comment: unclear question and I don't know why you want to do this

Comment: And I'm sure its not possible

Comment: And I don't know why you downvoted my answer

Comment: I posted it before the edit he made

Comment: And I answered what I knew

Comment: @Ehsan I can't even downvote yet mate

Comment: You just want to change the compiler

Comment: While the specific thing you want to do is not possible (and not necessary -- just use funciton syntax!), you may be interested in a C preprocessor library which I stumbeld upon recently, maintained by a SO contributor: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/. It seems to add a lot of cool things to standard C and is certainly worth a look if you are interested in sophisticated preprocessor exploits.

Comment: @PeterSchneider thank you buddy, I'll look into it.

Comment: `Base *b = new Base;` is a bad idea in C++ and an even worse one in C !

Comment: I've seen some pretty weird preprocessor hacks, but I've **never** seen anyone removing the parenthesis from C syntax.

Comment: @M.M why would it be even worse in C?

Comment: You could use C-style idioms that everyone will recognize. Even if you figured out a way to make `new T` work, everyone will wonder what on earth is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny enough you may get away with just defining `new` away (`#define new`) and defining a token for each constructor-like function which produces a real function call with brackets, like `#define BASE Base()`.

That should make the following code legal C:

```
#define new
#define class struct
#define BASE Base()

// forward declaration
class Base;
extern class Base *Base();

void f()
{
    class Base* b = new BASE;
}
```

Comment: HAHAHAHA it worked :D I can write class Base* b = new Base(); now, cheers mate. This is going to be a trollfest. Cheers buddy

Comment: Yeah, that was easy, wasn't it ;-). One word of technical caution (in addition to the general words of caution by Joachim and MM): `extern class Base *Base();` would not compile in C++ because the struct tags (here `Base` from `struct Base`) live in a different "name space" in C , but not in C++ where they consitute proper type names and hence clash with the function name.

Comment: Ye i rewrote some of the code so new Base(args...) can be used exactly like in C++, its kind of cool. Thanks alot mate

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want. If you have a macro with a parameter, such as `#define func(x) Func(x)`, then you need to call it as you would call a function:

```
#define func(x) Func(x)
func(x) // Will be replaced by Func(x) during pre-processing
```

If you have a macro without parameter, then the value is simply replaced during pre-processing:

```
#define MY_VAL 110
func(MY_VAL) // Will be replaced by Func (110) during pre-processing
```

It is easy enough to remove the first bracket...

```
#define func Func(
func 10);
```

... is perfectly valid, but quite odd. I don't think there is a way to remove the closing bracket, unfortunately.

As Joachim Pileborg pointed out in his comments, I don't see a *good* reason to do that in a real `C` program.